# Socket timeout after some time

Tags: tcl

If the server went into a infinite loop, how we can close the server connection after sometime?

Here is the code in which I am trying:

```
    set s [socket $host $port]
    fconfigure $s -blocking 1 -buffering line
    after 2000 set end 1
    vwait end
    if { $s != "" } {

            puts -nonewline $s "$msg\n.\n"
            flush $s
            fileevent $s readable [set answer [read $s]]

            puts "$answer"

            if {[catch {close $s}]} {
                    puts "Server hanged"
            }
```

This above code is working if the answer was given by the server without any problem. If the server went into infinite loop, it is keep on hanging in `read $s`. Please help on how to handle this `read socket` in a non-blocking mode as like in `fconfigure`.

Comment: I don't have an answer right now, but be aware that the way you invoke `fileevent` does _not_ install `[set answer [read $s]]` as a callback script. Instead, it performs that action (attempts to read from the socket and assigns the result to `answer`) during that invocation, and sets whatever was read from the socket as a callback script, which is very unlikely to be what you intended.

Comment: Incerease the time out period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using blocking sockets, you'll have this problem: putting the channel in non-blocking mode is the fix (together with using `after` to write a timeout). This does mean that you'll have to deal with all the complexity of asynchronous programming, but that's the tradeoff that you need here.

The two places where things can hang are in connection establishment and in production of the data. You would therefore use asynchronous connection and non-blocking retrieval.

```
set s [socket -async $host $port]
fconfigure $s -blocking 0

fileevent $s writeable [list connected $s]
proc connected {s} {
    global msg
    fileevent $s writeable {}
    puts -nonewline $s "$msg\n.\n"
    flush $s
    fileevent $s readable [list accumulateBytes $s]
}

set accumulate ""
proc accumulateBytes {s} {
    global accumulate end
    append accumulate [read $s]
    if {[eof $s]} {
        set end 0
    }
}

# Longer *total* time to connect and communicate.
after 5000 set end 1
vwait end

catch {close $s}

if {$end} {puts "timed out"}
puts "received message: $accumulate"
```